# Spring unit test of restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(..).setReadTimeout(..).build() throws null pointer exception

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

Unit test of

```
RestTemplate restTemplate =restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(connectTimeout)).setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(readTimeout))
```

Throws null pointer exception.

I have mocked RestTemplateBuilder,
RestTemplate is not able to understand which field is causing NPE

below is the sample code:

```
@Service
public class MySeriveClass{
@Autowired
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;
private int connectTimeout=10;
private int readTimeout = 10;
public boolean restTemplate_check()
{
   RestTemplate restTemplate  = restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(connectTimeout))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(readTimeout))
                .build();
//more code
return true;
}
}
//class end
```

Unit test code:

```
public class MySeriveClass_Test {

@InjectMocks
MySeriveClass mySeriveClass;

@Test 
public void restTemplate_check_test()
{
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        //bellow line throws null pointer exception
        org.mockito.BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
          .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).build()).willReturn(restTemplate);

        org.mockito.BDDMockito.given( mySeriveClass.restTemplate_check()).willReturn(true);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(true,  mySeriveClass.restTemplate_check());
}
}//test class ends
```

Comment: Can you add stack trace? Where is your resttemplatebuilder defined? Can you show me how it is getting instaciated?

Comment: @ParthManaktala RestTemplateBuilder is autowired in service class.

Answer (score 0):

The below test works fine.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MySeriveClass_Test  {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @InjectMocks
    Service mySeriveClass;

    @Test
    void restTemplate_check_test() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        // Broke the below line instead of all at once
        org.mockito.BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .willReturn(restTemplateBuilder);

        org.mockito.BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .willReturn(restTemplateBuilder);

        org.mockito.BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.build()).willReturn(restTemplate);

        assertEquals(true, mySeriveClass.restTemplate_check());
    }

}
```